# Get reference to key stored in GHashTable

Tags: c, hashtable, associative-array, glib

I'm using a GHashTable from glib and I want to delete a key value pair by key. As described in the [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-remove) when calling `g_hash_table_remove()` you need to free the key and value yourself when they were dynamically allocated. But how do I get a pointer to the key so I can free it?

EDIT: I considered using `g_hash_table_new_full` but my use of GHashTable is so small that I considered this overkill. I would prefer freeing the key manually.

EDIT: As pointed out by Keine Lust `g_hash_table_new_full` shouldn't be less performant. You can also pass `NULL` for one of the destroy functions if you don't need it.

Comment: Please give a reason for downvoting, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to `free` the associated data when an entry is deleted in the hash table is passing a `free` function to `g_hash_table_new_full`:

```
GHashTable = g_hash_table_new_full (g_str_hash, g_str_equal, g_free, g_free);
```

**Parameters**

> **hash_func:** a function to create a hash value from a key
>
> **key_equal_func:** a function to check two keys for equality
>
> **key_destroy_func:** a function to free the memory allocated for the key
> used when removing the entry from the GHashTable, or NULL if you don't
> want to supply such a function.
>
> **value_destroy_func:** a function to free the memory allocated for the
> value used when removing the entry from the GHashTable, or NULL if you
> don't want to supply such a function.

Comment: I considered using `g_hash_table_new_full` but my use of GHashTable is so small that I considered this overkill. I would prefer freeing the key manually.

Comment: Don't worry, there is no overkill in using `g_hash_table_new_full`, it just fills  2 members in the base struct: `hash_table->key_destroy_func` and `hash_table->value_destroy_func`, in fact, `g_hash_table_new` is implemented as  `return g_hash_table_new_full (hash_func, key_equal_func, NULL, NULL);`, behind the scene, take a look to the implementation: https://git.gnome.org//browse/glib/tree/glib/ghash.c

Comment: Thanks for making that clear, I'll happily go with `g_hash_table_new_full` then.